# Java Scanner util throwing exception when asking user for an email address

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to write a roster program for class.

The assignment asks that you input your own information to the program.

To do this, I added a scanner section into my test class to a new Student object (me) in which it asks me for all constructor parameters.

One of these is email address. I can't get it to work, because every time I input my email address I get a flurry of exceptions.

Here is an example of the output:

```
What is your first name?
Banning
What is your last name?
Lyth
What is your email address?
banninglyth@live.com
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at StudentRosterBLYTH.StudentRosterTest.main(StudentRosterTest.java:68)
C:\Users\banni\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

and here is the test class as far as I have it. The last section is throwing the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author banni
*/
public class StudentRosterTest {
    static int studentID;
    static String firstName
    static String lastName;
    static String emailAddress;
    static int age;
    static int[] grades;
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <Student> students = new ArrayList <Student> ();

        students.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age));
        studentID = 1;
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Smith";
        emailAddress = "John1989@google.com";
        age = 20;

        students.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age));
        studentID = 2;
        firstName = "Suzan";
        lastName = "Erickson";
        emailAddress = "Erickson_1990@gmail.com";
        age = 19;

        students.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age));
        studentID = 3;
        firstName = "Jack";
        lastName = "Napol";
        emailAddress = "The_Lawyer99yahoo.com";
        age = 19;

        students.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age));
        studentID = 4;
        firstName = "Erin";
        lastName = "Black";
        emailAddress = "Erin.black@comcast.net";
        age = 22;

        students.add(new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age));
        studentID = 5;
        //Begin asking for new Student entry
        firstName = input.next();
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        lastName = input.next();
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        emailAddress = input.next();
        System.out.println("What is your email address?");
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How old are you?");

    }
}
```

So, my question to all of you is, what am I doing wrong? Is it the At-Sign or am I just completely off?

Also, what gives? I just posted this a minute ago and already have -rep? wat.png

Comment: Maybe switch the "asking for input" and "printing question" around... And please debug your code.

Comment: Don't you think that you need to ask a question first and only then expect an answer?

Comment: @luk2302 I just tried that and not only does the order of questions go wonky, but the errors still occur

Comment: but, @PM77-1 switching them all around did help.. It is now successful. Thank you, I for some reason learned it the other way around, but Java is much more logical than that. whoops.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nextInt() when asking for e-mail, your next calls are all off by one. You should use .nextLine() for String input and .nextInt() for age.

```
studentID = 5;
//Begin asking for new Student entry
System.out.println("What is your first name?");
firstName = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your last name?");
lastName = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your email address?");
emailAddress = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("How old are you?");
age = input.nextInt();
```